# Postfix sending emails with delay

Tags: email, postfix, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-lightsail

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on Amazon Lightsail. I just configures Postfix to send emails.

- If I send an email after a few hours the email is received instantly.
- If I send multiple emails at one the emails get delayed for about 10-30 minutes.

**Questions:**

1. How to I fix the delay so that emails are sent instantly?
2. How to I make sure that all emails sent to users (root & ubuntu) by local applications get sent to an outward email that has the same domain?

My configuration:

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.x.x.x
search ec2.internal
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       webserver.DOMAIN-NAME.com webserver
3x.x.x.x        webserver.DOMAIN-NAME.com webserver #3.x.x.x is the IP that is mentioned in domain DNS

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

/etc/hostname

```
webserver
```

/etc/aliases

```
postmaster:    root
root:          myemail@address.com
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = webserver.DOMAIN-NAME.com
mydomain = DOMAIN-NAME.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
myorigin = $mydomain
#mydestination = $myhostname, DOMAIN-NAME.com, webserver.DOMAIN-NAME.com, localhost.DOMAIN-NAME.com, localhost
mydestination =
#relayhost =
relayhost = $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
#inet_interfaces = all
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
#inet_protocols = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

/var/log/mail.log

```
May  1 02:17:15 webserver postfix/smtp[6105]: 0287CC775F: to=<alex@DOMAIN-NAME.com>, relay=alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.190.27]:25, delay=531, delays=465/0.01/64/1.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1493605035 h2si13051738qte.100 - gsmtp)
May  1 02:17:15 webserver postfix/qmgr[6102]: 0287CC775F: removed
May  1 02:17:40 webserver postfix/smtp[6107]: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.190.27]:25: Connection timed out
May  1 02:17:40 webserver postfix/smtp[6108]: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.190.27]:25: Connection timed out
May  1 02:18:10 webserver postfix/smtp[6108]: connect to aspmx2.googlemail.com[64.233.190.27]:25: Connection timed out
May  1 02:18:10 webserver postfix/smtp[6107]: connect to aspmx3.googlemail.com[209.85.203.26]:25: Connection timed out
May  1 02:18:40 webserver postfix/smtp[6108]: connect to aspmx3.googlemail.com[209.85.203.26]:25: Connection timed out
May  1 02:18:40 webserver postfix/smtp[6107]: connect to aspmx2.googlemail.com[64.233.190.27]:25: Connection timed out
May  1 02:18:40 webserver postfix/smtp[6108]: CBE50C77C6: to=<alex@DOMAIN-NAME.com>, relay=none, delay=7845, delays=7695/0.02/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to aspmx3.googlemail.com[209.85.203.26]:25: Connection timed out)
May  1 02:18:40 webserver postfix/smtp[6107]: 2266DC775D: to=<alex123@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=174, delays=24/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to aspmx2.googlemail.com[64.233.190.27]:25: Connection timed out)
May  1 02:20:02 webserver postfix/scache[6110]: statistics: start interval May  1 02:16:41
May  1 02:20:02 webserver postfix/scache[6110]: statistics: domain lookup hits=0 miss=1 success=0%
May  1 02:20:02 webserver postfix/scache[6110]: statistics: address lookup hits=0 miss=2 success=0%
May  1 02:20:02 webserver postfix/scache[6110]: statistics: max simultaneous domains=1 addresses=1 connection=1
May  1 02:26:10 webserver postfix/qmgr[6102]: 2266DC775D: from=<ubuntu@webserver.DOMAIN-NAME.com>, size=425, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  1 02:26:10 webserver postfix/smtp[6138]: 2266DC775D: to=<alex123@gmail.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[209.85.201.26]:25, delay=625, delays=624/0.01/0.09/0.18, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1493605570 p15si12740899qta.122 - gsmtp)
May  1 02:26:10 webserver postfix/qmgr[6102]: 2266DC775D: removed
```

Comment: What makes you think that the delay is caused by your Postfix installation?

Comment: I have another server I am testing with Amazon linux/Sendmail on it and it sends emails out as soon as I feed the command. I maybe wrong here though as I am beginning to learn Ubuntu. Is the delay being caused by something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Lightsail is a low-end low-price cloud VPS solution for web application developers. Everything on [Lightsail documentation](https://amazonlightsail.com/docs/) is related to choosing and configuring web servers and CMS platforms. It is not clearly stated but otherwise apparent that Lightsail isn't ment to be an email server. Even the very name of your server is `webserver`!

A web application might send an emails every once in a while. Therefore SMTP port 25 is not completely blocked but rather has limitations. Your Postfix configuration is ok for a stand-alone SMTP server, but the `mail.log` shows what is happening: after you reach the limitation, SMTP connections gets timed out and the mail gets `deferred`, postponed for a later try. The [RFC 3463](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463) based [SMTP status code](https://wiki.mattrude.com/SMTP_Status_Codes) `dsn=4.4.1` tells the same:

> `4.4.1` **The recipient’s server is not responding**
>
> This is an error emanating from your server indicating that the
> recipient’s server is not responding. Your server will automatically
> try again a number of times – how many depends on how your server has
> been configured.

You mentioned in a comment that this only happens with Postfix on Ubuntu but not with Sendmail on Amazon Linux. I'm not so familiar with Amazon Linux and Amazon [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/), but I guess that Amazon Linux Sendmail might have Amazon SES preconfigured as a relay. It is possible to [integrate Amazon SES with Postfix](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html), too.

As you have `relayhost = $mydomain`, you probably are trying to relay all mail to an external mail server of your domain, as it should be. However, the limitation on port `25` doesn't have exception for your external MTA. Therefore, you should **use *message submission agent* (port `587`) instead**.

1. You have to have MSA configured in your email server. If it's also Postfix, you should have `/etc/postfix/master.cf` section beginning with `submission` uncommented:

   ```
    submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
      -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
   ```
2. Configure your Lightsail `relayhost` to use submission port and authentication, `main.cf`:

   ```
    relayhost = $mydomain:587
    # Alternative example without DNS MX lookup:
    # relayhost = [mail.example.com]:587
    smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
    smtp_use_tls = yes
    smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
    smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
   ```
3. The `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` is a [Berkeley DB](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types) (`hash:`) for the username and password information to be used for authenticating with the mail gateway server. Examples:

   ```
    # destination                   credentials
    [mail.example.com]              username:password
    # Alternative form:
    # [mail.example.com]:submission username:password
   ```

For more detailed information, see [Postfix SASL Howto](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html).

Comment: So basically it's Amazon that is deferring the emails. Thank you for your suggestions, I am implementing them right now and will get back :)

Comment: It would be nice if they told it somewhere, but based on the evidence, so it seems. Please let me know if using the submission helped.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked, I had to open another port on the server in order to achieve it. I also found out how we can request Amazon to life the restriction using this link: https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request?catalog=true&isauthcode=true Can you please add this link to your aswer as well so it's complete.

Comment: Your link is behind a login and therefore I'm not able to confirm. But good that there is an option to request for less restrictions. I'm sure it is enough to have it here on comments, so I'll just flag it as useful.